# Как изменить расстояние между элементами QComboBox?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qss, qcombobox

Мне нужно добавить свободного пространства между самим виджетом QComboBox и выпадающим списком.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот таблица стилей:

```
 QComboBox {
    
    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);
 }

QComboBox:hover {
    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);
}
QComboBox:focus {
    border: 2px solid rgb(140, 146, 255);
}

QComboBox::drop-down 
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    selection-background-color: rgb(140, 146, 255);
    
}

QComboBox QListView{
outline: 0px;
}





/* ===================== QScrollBar ======================= */
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);
    width: 10px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: rgb(194, 194, 255);       
    min-height: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(./images/up_arrow_disabled.png);        
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px; 
    border-image: url(./images/up_arrow_disabled.png);      
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(./images/up_arrow.png);                 
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

 QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить:

```
/* vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv */
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    margin-top: 20px;    
}
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

            
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.items_list=[
            "C", "C++", "Java", "Python", "PyQt", "JavaScript", 
            "C#", "Swift", "go", "Ruby", "Lua", "PHP"
        ]
        
        self.comboBox = QComboBox(self, minimumWidth=200)
        self.comboBox.addItems(self.items_list)
        self.comboBox.activated.connect(self.on_combobox1_Activate)
        
        self.comboBox.view().window().setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.comboBox.view().window().setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)        

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        
    def on_combobox1_Activate(self, index):
        print(f'index = {self.comboBox.currentIndex()}; Text = {self.comboBox.currentText()}\n')


style = '''
QComboBox {
    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);
}
QComboBox:hover {
    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);
}
QComboBox:focus {
    border: 2px solid rgb(140, 146, 255);
}
QComboBox::drop-down {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);    
    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    selection-background-color: rgb(140, 146, 255);
}
QComboBox QListView{
    outline: 0px;
}

/* ===================== QScrollBar ======================= */
QScrollBar:vertical {
    background-color: #2A2929;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 15px 3px 15px 3px;
    border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: #55D8C1;         
    min-height: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(./images/up_arrow_disabled.png);        
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(./images/down_arrow_disabled.png);       
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(./images/up_arrow.png);                 
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover, QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(./images/down_arrow.png);                
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
 QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}

/* vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv */
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    margin-top: 20px;    
}
'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(style)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]